# How to group previously-denormalized-data from a row

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing courses run by teachers, I want to grab the number of taught days and split these by years and teachers' status.

The table contains the following fields:

```
id  teacher_id   course_name  course_date  course_duration  teacher_status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Teacher_01   Course_AA    2012-02-01   2                volunteer
2   Teacher_02   Course_BB    2012-02-01   7                employee
3   Teacher_03   Course_BB    2013-02-01   7                contractor
4   Teacher_01   Course_AA    2014-02-01   2                paid volunteer
5   Teacher_04   Course_AA    2014-06-01   2                paid volunteer
```

Teachers may run a course under various statuses: volunteer, paid volunteer, contractor, employee, etc. The status of a given teacher can change through time. The duration of a course is expressed in days.

I can already gather the sum of taught days by teachers, split by status. This is done by

```sql
SELECT
    teacher_status,
    sum(course_duration)  AS "Taught days"
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    teacher_status
;
```

But data is not normalized and different families of statuses have been mixed. So I want to gather the same info (number of taught days) split:

- by 3 statuses: volunteer, paid volunteer, all other statuses,
- and by years.

What is expected is:

```
Year    Teacher_status      Taught_days
---------------------------------------
2012    volunteer           2
2012    employee            7
2013    contractor          7
2014    paid volunteer      4
```

I've tried various combinations of aggregate functions, `GROUP BY` / `HAVING` / `ROLLUP` statements but without success. How should I achieve this?

Comment: It would help greatly to give the expected results from the data that you give.

Comment: @jeremy Thank you, question has just been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to select a [complex expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) and then `GROUP BY` that, not just by a raw column value. You could either repeat the expression or, in Postgres, also refer to the column alias:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(year FROM course_date) as year,
    (CASE teacher_status
       WHEN 'volunteer' THEN 'volunteer'
       WHEN 'paid volunteer' THEN 'paid'
       ELSE 'other'
    END) AS status,
    SUM(course_duration) AS "Taught days"
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    year,
    status;
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work: `[42803] ERROR: column "teacher_status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @MatthieuFAURE Yeah, right, you'd need to do the same in the `SELECT` clause. Also I stole the year extract from ThomasB :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get your example result, I have this query

```sql
SELECT extract (year from course_date), 
    teacher_status,
    sum(course_duration)  AS "Taught days"
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    extract (year from course_date), 
    teacher_status;
```